# Expectation Probability (Need help with Geometric Series Part)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Suppose that independent trials, each of which is equally likely to have any of $m$ possible outcome, are performed until the same outcome occurs $k$ consecutive times. If $N$ denotes the number of trials, show that
$$E[N] = \frac{m^k-1}{m-1}$$

Hello, I'm having a lot of trouble with this question:
Attempt:
Let:
$N_k$ represent the time until the same outcome happens k consecutive times.
Clearly,the probability we get a single possible outcome on  a turn is a $1/m$.
Say $N_k$ has already happened ("given: $N_k$"). The probability that the $k+1$ time is the same outcome is $1/m$--thus we only need one more time/turn to get $k$+$1$ outcomes to occur consecutively.
The probability that you don't get the same outcome on the $k+1$ time is $(m-1)/m$. If you don't get the same outcome then you have to start over.  The mean number of extra trials you need is then: $E[N_{k+1}]$.

Thus:
$E[N_{k+1}|N_k]$=$N_{k}$+$(\frac{1}{m})$+($\frac{(m-1)}{m}$)$E[N_{k+1}]$.

Taking the expectation of both sides yields:
$E[N_{k+1}]$=$E[{N_k}]$+$(\frac{1}{m})$+($\frac{(m-1)}{m}$)$E[N_{k+1}]$.
Solving for, we get:
$E[N_{k+1}]$=$mE[N_k]+1$.
Thus we have:

$E[N_{k+1}]$=$1+m(1+mE[N_{k-1}])$

=$1+m+m^2E[N_{k-1}])$

..
..

$=1+m+.... m^{k}E[N_1]$  --(Not sure if this step) is right.

$=1+m+.... m^{k}$

But then I'm not sure how to get:$$E[N] = \frac{m^k-1}{m-1}$$.  Does it have to do with geometric series?

Comment: Yes it is about the geometric series. Now you obtain the expression for $E[N_{k+1}]$, you just need to shift back to $N_k$ and then we usually will directly write this result without step. If you do not see it yet, multiply the series by $m-1$ and see what you get.

Comment: @BGM I shifted back to $N_k$ and multiplied by (m-1) but I don't see anything.  What are our summands for geometric sum (from what to what)?

Comment: You should see very nice cancellations happen after you expand the product. What have you got?

Comment: @BGM $E(N_k)$=$1+m+...m^{k-1}$. multiplying by (m-1) yields:$ (m-1)+m*(m-1)+...(m-1)*m^{k-1}$?

Comment: Expand all. Do not keep the bracket.

Comment: @BGM so $m-1+m^2-m+m^3-m^2$ etc.....=$-1+m+m^2...$ I'm slightly confused

Comment: @BGM: So at the end we get: $m^k-1$?

Comment: @BGM thanks So if $E[N_k]$=$m^k-1$?, why does $E[N]=\frac{m^{k-1}}{m-1}$ Is it because we multiplied the series by m-1 so we are dividing out by m-1?

Comment: I think you get all the ideas and you have verified the geometric series once by yourself. You have obtained $(m - 1)E[N_k] = m^k - 1$ and that is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want $k$ in a row, so you want $E(N_k),$ not $E(N_{k+1})$.  That reduces the terms in your sum by $1$, giving
$$E(N_k)=1+m+m^2+\ldots m^{k-1}$$
This is a finite [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with sum $$\frac {m^k-1}{m-1}$$
To prove that, multiply both sides by $m$ and subtract the old one from the new one.

Comment: Thanks makes perfect sense.

Comment: Does my logic for my other steps of the question make sense, just want to make sure I did the problem correctly, thank you.

Comment: Yes, your logic is fine.  That is why I started where I did.